# Sending email only when the filled email and phone number are filled correct

Tags: php, jquery, html, email, contact-form

I have the following code in the sendmail.php file.

```
<?php

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'example@gmail.com';

    // Form fields
    $clientName = addslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
    $clientEmail = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $number = addslashes(trim($_POST['number']));
    $message = addslashes(trim($_POST['message']));

    // Email Ssubject
    $subject = 'Query from My Domain';

    // Compose message to send
    $sendMessage = 'Hi' . "\n\n";
    $sendMessage .= $message . "\n\n";
    $sendMessage .= 'From: ' . $clientName . "\n";
    $sendMessage .= 'Email: ' . $clientEmail . "\n";
    $sendMessage .= 'Contact number: ' . $number . "\n";

    $array = array();
    $array['nameMessage'] = '';
    $array['emailMessage'] = '';
    $array['numberMessage'] = '';
    $array['messageMessage'] = '';

    if($clientName == '') {
        $array['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your full name.';
    }
    if (filter_var($clientEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) {
        $array['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
    } 
    if (!preg_match('/^(\+?)+([0-9]{10,})$/', $number)) {
        $array['numberMessage'] = 'Please enter a valid contact number.';
    }
    if($message == '') {
        $array['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
    }
    if($clientName && $clientEmail && $number && $message != '') {
        // Headers
        $headers = "From: " . $clientName . ' <' . $clientEmail . '>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "CC: " . 'My Boss <boss@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;".PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= " boundary=\"boundary_sdfsfsdfs345345sfsgs\"";

        // Send mail
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $sendMessage, $headers);
    }

    echo json_encode($array);

}   else {
        header ('location: index.html#contact');
}

?>
```

In this from the email and phone number inputs are validated, and these validation works great. My problem is manipulating this section below so that the form send the email only when the filled email and phone number are correct. If I am not mistaken, what I need to fiddle with in the piece of code below is $clientEmail and $number, I tried many things that didn't work.

```
if($clientName  != '' && $clientEmail && $number && $message != '') {
    // Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $clientName . ' <' . $clientEmail . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "CC: " . 'My Boss <boss@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;".PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= " boundary=\"boundary_sdfsfsdfs345345sfsgs\"";

    // Send mail
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $sendMessage, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all your validation, and before you start to build the headers for the email, do this:

```
$isValid = empty($array['nameMessage']) && empty($array['emailMessage']) &&
           empty($array['numberMessage']) && empty($array['messageMessage']);
```

`$isValid` will be true if the form is valid. Now check for it before you send mail:

```
if($isValid) {
    // build headers and send mail
    ...
    mail(...);
    // maybe you should echo a success message and exit here 
    // if there is nothing else to do
}else{
    echo json_encode($array); //echo the error messages
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code seem to have address the validation problems I had. However I still don't get the email. I suspect the code might lie in the jQuery script that I have working with php and html. if(json.nameMessage === '' && json.emailMessage === '' && json.numberMessage === '' && json.messageMessage === '') {
      form.fadeOut('fast', function() {
       form.parent('.contact-form').append('<h2 class="text-center"><span class="orange">Thanks for contacting us!</span> We will get back to you very soon.</h2>');
      });
     }. The form doesn't fade and no message is displayed

Comment: You're welcome. If this addressed the problems you had, I suggest you select the answer.  What you're asking about (jQuery) is about something else. Consider opening a new question for it.

Comment: Thank you very much @BeetleJouce, I will open a new questions for it.